# sql denomination fill in list of employess

Tags: sql

sql in amount denomination fill in 1000,500,100,50,20,10,5,2,1

Answer (score -2):

DECLARE @Dividend INT
    ,@Dividend1 INT
    ,@Dividend2 INT
    ,@Dividend3 INT
    ,@Dividend4 INT
    ,@Dividend5 INT
    ,@Dividend6 INT
    ,@Dividend7 INT
    ,@Dividend8 INT
    ,@Dividend9 INT
    ,@Dividend10 INT
    ,@Dividend11 INT
    ,@Dividend12 INT
    ,@Dividend13 INT
    ,@Dividend14 INT
    ,@Dividend15 INT
    ,@Dividend16 INT
    ,@Divisor INT
    ,@Quotient INT
    ,@Remainder INT
    ,@EmployeeID BIGINT
    ,@EmployeeName VARCHAR(200)
    ,@Quotient1000 BIGINT
    ,@Quotient500 BIGINT
    ,@Quotient100 BIGINT
    ,@Quotient50 BIGINT
    ,@Quotient20 BIGINT
    ,@Quotient10 BIGINT
    ,@Quotient5 BIGINT
    ,@Quotient2 BIGINT
    ,@Quotient1 BIGINT

--select EmployeeID,EmployeeName from SALARYGEN1
SET @EmployeeID = (
        SELECT EmployeeID
        FROM SALARYGEN1
        )
SET @EmployeeName = (
        SELECT EmployeeName
        FROM SALARYGEN1
        )
SET @Dividend = (
        SELECT NetsaLARY
        FROM SALARYGEN1
        WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID
        )

IF (@Dividend >= 1000)
BEGIN
    IF (@Dividend >= 1000)
    BEGIN
        --insert into sa164 values(@Number)
        --SET @Dividend =40
        SET @Divisor = 1000

```
    SELECT @Quotient1000 = @Dividend / @Divisor

    ---ationhist values(@Quotient)
    PRINT 'Value of Quotient1000= ' + convert(VARCHAR, @Quotient1000)

    --insert into dec(EmployeeId,EmployeeName,Quotient1000) values(@EmployeeID,@EmployeeName,@Quotient)
    SELECT @Remainder = @Dividend % @Divisor

    SET @Dividend2 = @Remainder
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @Dividend2 = @Remainder
    SET @Quotient1000 = 0

    PRINT 'Value of Quotient1000= ' + convert(VARCHAR, @Quotient)
END

IF (@Dividend2 >= 500)
BEGIN
    SET @Divisor = 500

    SELECT @Quotient500 = @Dividend2 / @Divisor

    SELECT @Remainder = @Dividend2 % @Divisor

    SET @Dividend3 = @Remainder

    PRINT 'Value of Quotient500= ' + convert(VARCHAR, @Quotient500)
        --insert into dec(EmployeeId,EmployeeName,Quotient500) values(@EmployeeID,@EmployeeName,@Quotient)
        --PRINT 'Value of Remainder= ' + convert(varchar,@Remainder)
        --PRINT 'The number is small.';  
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @Dividend3 = @Remainder
    SET @Quotient500 = 0

    --set @Quotient=0
    PRINT 'Value of Quotient500= ' + convert(VARCHAR, @Quotient)
END

IF (@Dividend3 >= 100)
BEGIN
    SET @Divisor = 100

    SELECT @Quotient100 = @Dividend3 / @Divisor

    SELECT @Remainder = @Dividend3 % @Divisor

    SET @Dividend4 = @Remainder

    PRINT 'Value of Quotient100= ' + convert(VARCHAR, @Quotient100)
        --PRINT 'Value of Remainder= ' + convert(varchar,@Remainder)
        --PRINT 'The number is small.';  
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @Dividend4 = @Remainder
    SET @Quotient100 = 0

    --set @Quotient=0
    PRINT 'Value of Quotient100= ' + convert(VARCHAR, @Quotient)
END

IF (@Dividend4 >= 50)
BEGIN
    SET @Divisor = 50

    SELECT @Quotient50 = @Dividend4 / @Divisor

    SELECT @Remainder = @Dividend4 % @Divisor

    SET @Dividend5 = @Remainder

    PRINT 'Value of Quotient50= ' + convert(VARCHAR, @Quotient50)
        --  PRINT 'Value of Remainder= ' + convert(varchar,@Remainder)
        --PRINT 'The number is small.';  
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @Dividend5 = @Remainder
    SET @Quotient50 = 0

    --set @Quotient=0
    PRINT 'Value of Quotient50= ' + convert(VARCHAR, @Quotient)
END

IF (@Dividend5 >= 20)
BEGIN
    SET @Divisor = 20

    SELECT @Quotient20 = @Dividend5 / @Divisor

    SELECT @Remainder = @Dividend5 % @Divisor

    SET @Dividend6 = @Remainder

    PRINT 'Value of Quotient20= ' + convert(VARCHAR, @Quotient20)
        --  PRINT 'Value of Remainder= ' + convert(varchar,@Remainder)
        --PRINT 'The number is small.';  
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @Dividend6 = @Remainder
    SET @Quotient20 = 0

    --set @Quotient=0
    PRINT 'Value of Quotient20= ' + convert(VARCHAR, @Quotient)
END

IF (@Dividend6 >= 10)
BEGIN
    SET @Divisor = 10

    SELECT @Quotient10 = @Dividend6 / @Divisor

    SELECT @Remainder = @Dividend6 % @Divisor

    SET @Dividend7 = @Remainder

    PRINT 'Value of Quotient10= ' + convert(VARCHAR, @Quotient10)
        --  PRINT 'Value of Remainder= ' + convert(varchar,@@Dividend10)
        --PRINT 'The number is small.';  
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @Dividend7 = @Remainder
    SET @Quotient10 = 0

    --set @Quotient=0
    PRINT 'Value of Quotient10= ' + convert(VARCHAR, @Quotient)
END

IF (@Dividend7 >= 5)
BEGIN
    SET @Divisor = 5

    SELECT @Quotient5 = @Dividend7 / @Divisor

    SELECT @Remainder = @Dividend7 % @Divisor

    SET @Dividend8 = @Remainder

    --SET @Dividend13=@Dividend10
    PRINT 'Value of Quotien5= ' + convert(VARCHAR, @Quotient5)
        --  PRINT 'Value of Remainder= ' + convert(varchar,@@Dividend10)
        --PRINT 'The number is small.';  
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @Dividend8 = @Remainder
    SET @Quotient5 = 0

    --set @Quotient=0
    PRINT 'Value of Quotient5= ' + convert(VARCHAR, @Quotient)
END

IF (@Dividend8 >= 2)
BEGIN
    SET @Divisor = 2

    SELECT @Quotient2 = @Dividend8 / @Divisor

    SELECT @Remainder = @Dividend8 % @Divisor

    SET @Dividend9 = @Remainder

    --SET @Dividend13=@Dividend10
    PRINT 'Value of Quotien2= ' + convert(VARCHAR, @Quotient2)
        --  PRINT 'Value of Remainder= ' + convert(varchar,@@Dividend10)
        --PRINT 'The number is small.';  
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    --/--SET @Dividend15 = @Remainder
    SET @Quotient2 = 0
    SET @Dividend9 = @Remainder

    --set @Quotient=0
    PRINT 'Value of Quotient2= ' + convert(VARCHAR, @Quotient)
END

IF (@Dividend9 >= 1)
BEGIN
    SET @Divisor = 1

    SELECT @Quotient1 = @Dividend9 / @Divisor

    SELECT @Remainder = @Dividend9 % @Divisor

    PRINT 'Value of Quotien1= ' + convert(VARCHAR, @Quotient1)
        --  PRINT 'Value of Remainder= ' + convert(varchar,@@Dividend10)
        --PRINT 'The number is small.';  
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @Dividend10 = @Remainder
    SET @Quotient1 = 0

    --set @Quotient=0
    PRINT 'Value of Quotient1= ' + convert(VARCHAR, @Quotient)
END

INSERT INTO DEC(EmployeeID, EmployeeName, Quotient1000, Quotient500, Quotient100, Quotient50, Quotient20, Quotient10, Quotient5, Quotient2, Quotient1,Activeflag,Createeddate)
VALUES (
    @EmployeeID
    ,@EmployeeName
    ,@Quotient1000
    ,@Quotient500
    ,@Quotient100
    ,@Quotient50
    ,@Quotient20
    ,@Quotient10
    ,@Quotient5
    ,@Quotient2
    ,@Quotient1
    ,1
    ,GETDATE()
    )
```

END
ELSE
    IF (@Dividend >= 500)
    BEGIN
        IF (@Dividend >= 500)
        BEGIN
            --insert into sa164 values(@Number)
            --SET @Dividend =40
            SET @Divisor = 500

```
        SELECT @Quotient = @Dividend / @Divisor

        --insert into denomationhist values(@Quotient)
        PRINT 'Value of Quotient500= ' + convert(VARCHAR, @Quotient)

        SELECT @Remainder = @Dividend % @Divisor

        SET @Dividend2 = @Remainder
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Dividend2 = @Remainder
        SET @Quotient = 0

        PRINT 'Value of Quotient500= ' + convert(VARCHAR, @Quotient)
    END

    IF (@Dividend2 >= 100)
    BEGIN
        SET @Divisor = 100

        SELECT @Quotient = @Dividend2 / @Divisor

        SELECT @Remainder = @Dividend2 % @Divisor

        SET @Dividend3 = @Remainder

        PRINT 'Value of Quotient100= ' + convert(VARCHAR, @Quotient)
            --PRINT 'Value of Remainder= ' + convert(varchar,@Remainder)
            --PRINT 'The number is small.';  
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Dividend3 = @Remainder
        SET @Quotient = 0

        --set @Quotient=0
        PRINT 'Value of Quotient100= ' + convert(VARCHAR, @Quotient)
    END

    IF (@Dividend3 >= 50)
    BEGIN
        SET @Divisor = 50

        SELECT @Quotient = @Dividend3 / @Divisor

        SELECT @Remainder = @Dividend3 % @Divisor

        SET @Dividend4 = @Remainder

        PRINT 'Value of Quotient50= ' + convert(VARCHAR, @Quotient)
            --PRINT 'Value of Remainder= ' + convert(varchar,@Remainder)
            --PRINT 'The number is small.';  
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Dividend4 = @Remainder
        SET @Quotient = 0

        --set @Quotient=0
        PRINT 'Value of Quotient50= ' + convert(VARCHAR, @Quotient)
    END

    IF (@Dividend4 >= 20)
    BEGIN
        SET @Divisor = 20

        SELECT @Quotient = @Dividend4 / @Divisor

        SELECT @Remainder = @Dividend4 % @Divisor

        SET @Dividend5 = @Remainder

        PRINT 'Value of Quotient20= ' + convert(VARCHAR, @Quotient)
            --  PRINT 'Value of Remainder= ' + convert(varchar,@Remainder)
            --PRINT 'The number is small.';  
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Dividend5 = @Remainder
        SET @Quotient = 0

        --set @Quotient=0
        PRINT 'Value of Quotient20= ' + convert(VARCHAR, @Quotient)
    END

    IF (@Dividend5 >= 10)
    BEGIN
        SET @Divisor = 10

        SELECT @Quotient = @Dividend5 / @Divisor

        SELECT @Remainder = @Dividend5 % @Divisor

        SET @Dividend6 = @Remainder

        PRINT 'Value of Quotient10= ' + convert(VARCHAR, @Quotient)
            --  PRINT 'Value of Remainder= ' + convert(varchar,@Remainder)
            --PRINT 'The number is small.';  
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Dividend6 = @Remainder
        SET @Quotient = 0

        --set @Quotient=0
        PRINT 'Value of Quotient10= ' + convert(VARCHAR, @Quotient)
    END

    IF (@Dividend6 >= 5)
    BEGIN
        SET @Divisor = 5

        SELECT @Quotient = @Dividend6 / @Divisor

        SELECT @Remainder = @Dividend6 % @Divisor

        SET @Dividend7 = @Remainder

        PRINT 'Value of Quotient5= ' + convert(VARCHAR, @Quotient)
            --  PRINT 'Value of Remainder= ' + convert(varchar,@@Dividend10)
            --PRINT 'The number is small.';  
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Dividend7 = @Remainder
        SET @Quotient = 0

        --set @Quotient=0
        PRINT 'Value of Quotient5= ' + convert(VARCHAR, @Quotient)
    END

    IF (@Dividend7 >= 2)
    BEGIN
        SET @Divisor = 2

        SELECT @Quotient = @Dividend7 / @Divisor

        SELECT @Remainder = @Dividend7 % @Divisor

        SET @Dividend8 = @Remainder

        --SET @Dividend13=@Dividend10
        PRINT 'Value of Quotien2= ' + convert(VARCHAR, @Quotient)
            --  PRINT 'Value of Remainder= ' + convert(varchar,@@Dividend10)
            --PRINT 'The number is small.';  
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Dividend8 = @Remainder
        SET @Quotient = 0

        --set @Quotient=0
        PRINT 'Value of Quotient2= ' + convert(VARCHAR, @Quotient)
    END

    IF (@Dividend8 >= 1)
    BEGIN
        SET @Divisor = 1

        SELECT @Quotient = @Dividend8 / @Divisor

        SELECT @Remainder = @Dividend8 % @Divisor

        SET @Dividend9 = @Remainder

        --SET @Dividend13=@Dividend10
        PRINT 'Value of Quotien1= ' + convert(VARCHAR, @Quotient)
            --  PRINT 'Value of Remainder= ' + convert(varchar,@@Dividend10)
            --PRINT 'The number is small.';  
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        --/--SET @Dividend15 = @Remainder
        SET @Quotient = 0
        SET @Dividend9 = @Remainder

        --set @Quotient=0
        PRINT 'Value of Quotient1= ' + convert(VARCHAR, @Quotient)
    END

    IF (@Dividend9 >= 1)
    BEGIN
        SET @Divisor = 1

        SELECT @Quotient = @Dividend9 / @Divisor

        SELECT @Remainder = @Dividend9 % @Divisor

        PRINT 'Value of Quotien1= ' + convert(VARCHAR, @Quotient)
            --  PRINT 'Value of Remainder= ' + convert(varchar,@@Dividend10)
            --PRINT 'The number is small.';  
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Dividend10 = @Remainder
        SET @Quotient = 0

        --set @Quotient=0
        PRINT 'Value of Quotient1= ' + convert(VARCHAR, @Quotient)
    END
END
```